# Forecasting in r: holtwinters function

Tags: r, forecasting, holtwinters

I am trying to forecast the data for daily basis.
If i use holtwinters function in r , i am getting warning message and not able to execute output

I used the below code

```
library(data.table)
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

ruta = "D:\\datasets/"

dt_ts = fread(paste0(ruta,"Actuals.csv"))
dt_ts[,Dates:=as.Date(Dates,"%Y-%m-%d")]

# Removing 29 february
dt_ts = dt_ts[!Dates %in% as.Date("2016-02-29")]

regions = unique(dt_ts$Regions)
items = unique(dt_ts$Item)

ls_pred=list()
ls_model=list()
i<-regions[1]
j<-items[1]
for(i in regions){
  for(j in items){
    name_model = paste(i," - ",j)

    ts_temp = ts(dt_ts[Regions==i & Item==j,]$Data,frequency = 365,start = 
 c(2016,1,1))
    # plot(ts_temp)

    model_hw = HoltWinters(ts_temp)
    pred_hw = forecast(model_hw,h=365)
    # plot(pred_hw)

    pred_hw$mean = ifelse(pred_hw$mean<0,0,pred_hw$mean)
    # plot(pred_hw)

    ls_model[[name_model]] = model_hw
    ls_pred[[name_model]] = pred_hw$mean    


  }
}
```

my data is as follows

```
Regions Item    Dates   Data
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    01-01-16    2
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    02-01-16    7
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    03-01-16    6
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    04-01-16    0
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    05-01-16    6
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    06-01-16    6
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    07-01-16    1
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    08-01-16    6
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    09-01-16    0
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    10-01-16    4
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    11-01-16    4
Tiruchengode    TRACTOR TT35-4WD    12-01-16    0
```

[image: I am getting the warning message as]

any suggestions please
Thanks in advance

Comment: Holt-Winters models generally do not work well for daily data. Try using `forecast::auto.arima` or `forecast::ets` instead.

Comment: For daily data you can also try the prophet package.